# So I've got the destiny Expansion Pass... Now what?

Tags: xbox-360, destiny

I got the expansion pass for Xbox. What do I do with it and how do I get the expansions I paid for?

Comment: Usually expansion/season pass means that when expansions release for the game, you are able to download them for "free". AFAIK, the first expansion for the game releases on December. When it does, you'll be able to download it without paying.

Comment: @JohnoBoy that's the right answer, you should make it one instead of just a comment.

Comment: My answer is based on assumptions and isn't necessarily correct for Destiny, therefore I'd rather leave it as a comment.

Comment: @JohnoBoy, *it is the right answer*. That's how it works, and that's how it always has worked. Add it as an answer and you'll get the up votes.

Answer (score 7):

When you purchase a season pass, you are prepurchasing any DLC that is stated to be included in the pass.

When each of these pieces of DLC becomes available you will be able to download them instantly at no extra cost.

Comment: It has been noted that Expansion I 'The Dark Below' should be released sometime in Decemeber (2014). I haven't seen anything regarding Expansion II release date, but one can assume that it'll be sometime towards the end of Q1 2015?